# Card with scroll in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

It's possible to create a v-list in vuetify with fixed height and when my user add some content he show a scrollbar in the v-list
tks

Answer (score 5):

What your asking is not entirely clear, but with CSS you can add a scroll bar to a card if its not automatic.

Here is the codepen: 
https://codepen.io/AleaQ/pen/WJZqWb

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex xs6>
      <v-card class="scroll" height="100">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

//CSS MARKUP
    .scroll {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

Comment: The CodePen link is broken.